# Call random function in JavSccript

Tags: javascript

My code looks like this:

```
var MyObj = {
   run: function() {
    //random function
     var fncRun = this.listFnc[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.listFnc.length)];
    //call function
     this.fncRun(args1, args2);
   },
   fnc1: function() {
     console.log('run with function 1');
   },
   fnc2: function(args1) {
     console.log('run with function 2');
   },
   fnc3: function(args1, args2) {
     console.log('run with function 3');
   },
   listFnc: new Array("fnc1","fnc2","fnc3"),
};

MyObj.run();
```

But not working, this is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
```

Can somebody can help me?

Comment: It's worth noting on top of @meagar's answer that this code will fail because `args1` and `args2` don't exist.

Comment: Why do we keep seeing `new Array()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `this.variable` to invoke a method name stored in a variable. There would be no way for JavaScript to tell whether you wanted to invoke a method called `variable` or a method whose name was *stored* in the variable. you need `this[variable]`:

```
 this[fncRun](args1, args2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues to fix:

1: args1 and args2 in run functions are undefined; add to run function

```
run: function(args1, args2) {
}
```

2: `var fncRun` is the **name** of the function, retreive the function like this:

```
this[fncRun](args1, args2);
```

new run function ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4XGT/)):

```
run: function(args1, args2) {
  //random function
  var fncRun = this.listFnc[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.listFnc.length)];
  //call function
  this[fncRun](args1, args2);
}
```